# Array size exceeds addressing limitation (C# vs C++)

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, marshalling

I have a C# program that manages huge arrays of Complex (greater than 2GB). 
This program compiled in x64 use the clausule gcAllowVeryLargeObjects=true in App.config:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

It needs to use Third party dlls, but the marshalling seem to fail when it passes these huges array to this external function.

This is the Exception "**Array size exceeds adressing limitation**"

It seems to be a VS CLR problem because I did this example to demostrate it.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyWrapper.MyTest();
    }
}

[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
public class MyWrapper    
{


    private MyWrapper()
    {
    }

    internal static int CS_foo(
    [In] Complex[,] A // text to prepend to converted integer
     )
    {
         Complex B_complex= new Complex(0, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++)
        {

            B_complex = A[0, i];
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format(" from C# A({0})\t{1}\ti{2}", i, B_complex.Real, B_complex.Imaginary));
        }
        return 0;
    }

    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
    [DllImport("DLL1.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = false)]
    internal static extern int C_foo(     
      [In] Complex[,] A// text to prepend to converted integer

     );


    public static void MyTest()
    {
        Complex[,]A = new Complex[12000, 12000];

        A[0, 0] = new Complex(0.1, -0.1);
        A[0, 1] = new Complex(11.0, 0.1);
        A[0, 5] = new Complex (55, -0.5);
        A[0, 9] = new Complex (99.0, 0.9);

        MyWrapper.CS_foo(A);
        MyWrapper.C_foo(A); //Here Fails!!            
    }
}
```

C++  DLL Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"


#ifndef Complex16
typedef
struct Complex16 {
    double real;
    double imag;
} Complex16;
#endif

extern "C" int __declspec(dllexport)  C_foo(
    Complex16* A 
    )

{
    Complex16  B;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {       
    B.real = A[i].real;
    B.imag = A[i].imag;
    printf("   hello from C A(%d)=( %f %f ) \n ", i, B.real, B.imag);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you change the array size (eg. 1200x1200) the example works! 
Any idea of how to solve this problem?

Thakyou

Comment: Please include a description of the failure: crash, exception or something else?

Comment: "Array size exceeds adressing limitation"

Comment: SO is not Microsoft's bug tracker, you'll have to take this up with Microsoft itself.  As-is, you'll have to deal with the limitation, you can't pinvoke with arrays bigger than 2GB and ~11500 x 11500 is where the buck stops.

Answer (score 1):

The solution can be found here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b02c61ab-8be1-4ed1-9752-9fa24211d78a/c-vs-c-array-size-exceeds-adressing-limitation?forum=csharpgeneral

in short:

the default marshaling doesn't like such large arrays. Pin the array and pass a pointer to its first element to the native function:

```
using System.Numerics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public unsafe class MyWrapper
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Complex[,] A = new Complex[12000, 12000];

        A[0, 0] = new Complex(0.1, -0.1);
        A[0, 1] = new Complex(11.0, 0.1);
        A[0, 5] = new Complex(55, -0.5);
        A[0, 9] = new Complex(99.0, 0.9);

        fixed (Complex* p = &A[0, 0])
            C_foo(p);
    }

    [DllImport("DLL1.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = false)]
    internal static extern int C_foo(Complex* A);
```